# hide project path in Android Studio title bar?

Tags: android-studio, titlebar

Is it possible to hide the path of the project being shown in the title bar of Android Studio?

I would like to have it as:
   "Project Name - Android Studio"

but instead now i have it like:
   "Project name [path/to/project/] - [app] - [/path/to/file/] - Android Studio - version number"

I looked everywhere in settings couldn't find an option for that.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no option for that as of IntelliJ IDEA 14.1 and Android Studio 1.2.

Answer (score 1):

You can deselect `Always show full path in window header` in the settings

[image]